# WCF vs Sync Framework

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework

We have an application that we developed using `ASP.Net` and the database is `SQL SERVER 2008 R2`. Now we are planning to decentralize this application. Then there will be one central database and several client databases. We have to synchronize all of these databases.

For example, in the morning all the updated master data have to be updated in the clients sites and in the night all the transactional data have to be updated on the central data bases.

What is the best way to achieve this using Microsoft technologies? So far I have thought of WCF service or the MS Synchronization framework.

Which is best?

What are limitations?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Sync framework for your scenario.  WCF is feasible but would require a fair bit of coding depending on how much data you are talking about.

A major consideration with the Sync framework is whether your SQLServers are on the same network or not.  If they are not on the same network, the app that performs the sync needs to be able to connect to the remote SQLServer.  If the remote SQLServer is behind a firewall, you will need to open a port which can be problematic (some security pros don't like having a SQLServer exposed publicly, even if it is over a port).

The other thing with the sync framework is that you have to have a timestamp column ( or equivalent I think from memory) on every table that you want to sync.  The framework will create a tracking table for every table you wish to sync.

Comment: Thank you very much it was really helping. Data capacity would roughly 500mb. By fair coding you mean?. The thing is these clients may connect either by using VPN or Internet.

Comment: by "a fair bit of coding" I mean potentially a lot of code if your database has many tables with many relationships.  The volume of data wouldn't be a major problem with WCF, it is more the size of your schema.